# RequireJS: Correct way of adding global dependencies

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I'm using a solution based on Durandal. I'm fairly new to things like require (so please correct me if I'm talking rubbish)

```
define(['durandal/http', 'durandal/app', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'durandal/plugins/notify'], function (http, app, router, notify) {
    var userInfo = {
        AccessFrom: ko.observable(),
        AccessTo: ko.observable()
        }    
...
});
```

I ran my javas cript file though [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) out of curiosity (which is completely new to me)... and it made me aware of the following.

I seemed to be getting a lot of "'ko' is not defined" warnings.

Its obviously because knockout hasn't been passed through as a dependency... I'm not sure how to exactly? Or do I have to for that matter?

My external libraries all get added to another scripts folder for bundling & compression purposes, and I don't think that adding 'something/something/something/scripts/knockout' to each dependent file is 100% right... (Although it would work I'd assume)

Is there a standard way to handle 3rd party libraries, or globally used libraries like jquery/knockout within the context of a require java-script function... or is this just wishful/confused thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durandal 1.2 expects knockoutjs, jquery, and requirejs are included globally by just including them in your page as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="knockout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

So, you don't have to worry about including them as dependencies when you define your AMD modules.
//

****EDIT****

RainerAtSpirit has pointed out that in the upcoming Durandal 2.0, ko and jquery will be loaded as AMD modules by default.

Comment: yes they are included globally. so as a rule of thumb.. the amd modules are only "custom" functions and never 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I think that would be safe to say. Unless you find a 3rd party library that is built as an amd module.

Comment: ... or unless you decide to upgrade to upcoming Durandal 2.0, where ko and jquery will be loaded as AMD modules by default. In regards to JSHint, it allows defining globals at the beginning of your files e.g. `/*global define, ko, YOUR, GLOBALS, HERE */`.

Comment: Why don't you just use the RequireJS [shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for resolving those dependencies:
`shim: { 'durandal': ['knockout', 'jquery'] };`